# Scala Branch And Bound Motif Search

Tags: scala, bioinformatics

Below code searches for a motif (of length 8) in a sequence(String) and, as the result, it has to give back sequence with the best score. **The problem is, although the code produces no errors, there is no output at all** (probably infinite cycle, I observe blank console).

I am gonna give all my code online and if that is required. In order to reproduce the problem,  just pass a number (between 0 and 3 - you can give 4 sequence, so you must choose 1 of them 0 is the first , 1 is the second etc) as args(0) (e.g. "0"), expected output should look something like "Motif = ctgatgta"

```
    import scala.util.control._

    object BranchAndBound {

      var seq: Array[String] = new Array[String](20)

      var startPos: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](20)

      var pickup: Array[String] = new Array[String](20)

      var bestMotif: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](20)

      var ScoreMatrix = Array.ofDim[Int](5, 20)

      var i: Int = _

      var j: Int = _

      var lmer: Int = _

      var t: Int = _

      def main(args: Array[String]) {

        var t1: Long = 0
        var t2: Long = 0

        t1 = 0
        t2 = 0
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()

        val seq0 = Array(
          Array(
            " >5 regulatory reagions with 69 bp",
            " cctgatagacgctatctggctatccaggtacttaggtcctctgtgcgaatctatgcgtttccaaccat",
            " agtactggtgtacatttgatccatacgtacaccggcaacctgaaacaaacgctcagaaccagaagtgc",
            " aaacgttagtgcaccctctttcttcgtggctctggccaacgagggctgatgtataagacgaaaatttt",
            " agcctccgatgtaagtcatagctgtaactattacctgccacccctattacatcttacgtccatataca",
            " ctgttatacaacgcgtcatggcggggtatgcgttttggtcgtcgtacgctcgatcgttaccgtacggc"),

          Array(
            " 2 columns mutants",
            " cctgatagacgctatctggctatccaggtacttaggtcctctgtgcgaatctatgcgtttccaaccat",
            " agtactggtgtacatttgatccatacgtacaccggcaacctgaaacaaacgctcagaaccagaagtgc",
            " aaacgttagtgcaccctctttcttcgtggctctggccaacgagggctgatgtataagacgaaaattttt",
            " agcctccgatgtaagtcatagctgtaactattacctgccacccctattacatcttacgtccatataca",
            " ctgttatacaacgcgtcatggcggggtatgcgttttggtcgtcgtacgctcgatcgttaccgtacggc"),

          Array(
            " 2 columns mutants",
            " cctgatagacgctatctggctatccaggtacttaggtcctctgtgcgaatctatgcgtttccaaccat",
            " agtactggtgtacatttgatccatacgtacaccggcaacctgaaacaaacgctcagaaccagaagtgc",
            " aaacgttagtgcaccctctttcttcgtggctctggccaacgagggctgatgtataagacgaaaattttt",
            " agcctccgatgtaagtcatagctgtaactattacctgccacccctattacatcttacgtccatataca",
            " ctgttatacaacgcgtcatggcggggtatgcgttttggtcgtcgtacgctcgatcgttaccgtacggc"),

          Array(
            " 2 columns mutants",
            " cctgatagacgctatctggctatccaggtacttaggtcctctgtgcgaatctatgcgtttccaaccat",
            " agtactggtgtacatttgatccatacgtacaccggcaacctgaaacaaacgctcagaaccagaagtgc",
            " aaacgttagtgcaccctctttcttcgtggctctggccaacgagggctgatgtataagacgaaaattttt",
            " agcctccgatgtaagtcatagctgtaactattacctgccacccctattacatcttacgtccatataca",
            " ctgttatacaacgcgtcatggcggggtatgcgttttggtcgtcgtacgctcgatcgttaccgtacggc"))

        var k: Int = 0
        var m: Int = 0
        var n: Int = 0
        var bestScore: Int = 0
        var optScore: Int = 0
        var get: Int = 0

        var ok1: Boolean = false
        var ok3: Boolean = false
        ok1 = false
        ok3 = false

        j = 1
        lmer = 8
        m = 1
        t = 5
        n = 69
        optScore = 0
        bestScore = 0

        k = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(args(0))
        j = 1

        while (j <= t) {
          seq(j) = new String()
          i = 0
          while (i < n) {
            seq(j) += seq0(k)(j).charAt(i)
            i += 1
          }
          j += 1
        }

        j = 1

        while (j <= t) {
          newPickup(1, j)
          j += 1
        }

        j = 0
        bestScore = 0
        i = 1

        val whilebreaker = new Breaks
        whilebreaker.breakable {
          while (i > 0) {

            if (i < t) {
              if (startPos(1) == (n - lmer)) whilebreaker.break

              val sc = Score()
              optScore = sc + (t - i) * lmer

              if (optScore < bestScore) {
                ok1 = false
                j = i

                val whilebreak1 = new Breaks
                whilebreak1.breakable {
                  while (j >= 1) {

                    if (startPos(j) < n - lmer) {
                      ok1 = true
                      newPickup(0, j)
                      whilebreak1.break
                    } else {
                      ok1 = true
                      newPickup(1, j)

                      val whilebreak2 = new Breaks
                      whilebreak2.breakable {
                        while (startPos(i - 1) == (n - lmer)) {
                          newPickup(1, i - 1)
                          i -= 1
                          if (i == 0) whilebreak2.break
                        }
                      }
                      if (i > 1) {
                        newPickup(0, i - 1)
                        i -= 1
                      }
                      whilebreak1.break
                    }
                  }
                }
                if (ok1 == false) i = 0
              } else {
                newPickup(1, i + 1)
                i += 1
              }
            } else {
              get = Score()
              if (get > bestScore) {
                bestScore = get
                m = 1
                while (m <= t) {
                  bestMotif(m) = startPos(m)
                  m += 1
                }
              }
              ok3 = false
              j = t

              val whilebreak3 = new Breaks
              whilebreak3.breakable {
                while (j >= 1) {
                  if (startPos(j) < n - lmer) {
                    ok3 = true
                    newPickup(0, j)
                    whilebreak3.break
                  } else {
                    ok3 = true
                    newPickup(1, j)

                    val whilebreak4 = new Breaks

                    whilebreak4.breakable {
                      while (startPos(i - 1) == (n - lmer)) {
                        newPickup(1, i - 1)
                        i -= 1
                        if (i == 0) whilebreak4.break
                      }
                    }
                    if (i > 1) {
                      newPickup(0, i - 1)
                      i -= 1
                    }
                    whilebreak3.break
                  }
                }
              }
              if (ok3 == false) i = 0
            }
          }
        }

        println("Motiv: " + Consensus())
        // println()

        j = 1

        while (j <= t) {
          t2 = System.currentTimeMillis()
          j += 1
        }

        println("time= " + (t2 - t1) + " ms")
      }

      def Score(): Int = {

        var j: Int = 0
        var k: Int = 0
        var m: Int = 0
        var max: Int = 0
        var sum: Int = 0
        sum = 0
        max = 0
        m = 1

        while (m <= lmer) {
          k = 1
          while (k <= 4) {
            ScoreMatrix(k)(m) = 0
            k += 1
          }
          m += 1
        }
        m = 1
        while (m <= lmer) {
          k = 1
          while (k <= i) pickup(k).charAt(m) match {
            case 'a' => ScoreMatrix(1)(m) += 1
            case 'c' => ScoreMatrix(2)(m) += 1
            case 'g' => ScoreMatrix(3)(m) += 1
            case 't' => ScoreMatrix(4)(m) += 1
          }
          m += 1
        }
        j = 1
        while (j <= lmer) {
          max = 0
          m = 1
          while (m <= 4) {
            if (ScoreMatrix(m)(j) > max) {
              max = ScoreMatrix(m)(j)
            }
            m += 1
          }
          sum += max
          j += 1
        }
        sum
      }

      def Consensus(): String = {
        var i: Int = 0
        var j: Int = 0
        var k: Int = 0
        var m: Int = 0
        var max: Int = 0
        var imax: Int = 0
        var str: String = null
        i = 1
        while (i <= t) {
          pickup(i) = " " +
            seq(i).substring(bestMotif(i), bestMotif(i) + lmer)
          i += 1
        }
        m = 1
        while (m <= lmer) {
          k = 1
          while (k <= 4) {
            ScoreMatrix(k)(m) = 0
            k += 1
          }
          m += 1
        }
        m = 1
        while (m <= lmer) {
          k = 1
          while (k <= t) pickup(k).charAt(m) match {
            case 'a' => ScoreMatrix(1)(m) += 1
            case 'c' => ScoreMatrix(2)(m) += 1
            case 'g' => ScoreMatrix(3)(m) += 1
            case 't' => ScoreMatrix(4)(m) += 1
          }
          m += 1
        }
        str = ""
        imax = 0
        j = 1
        while (j <= lmer) {
          max = 0
          i = 1
          while (i <= 4) {
            if (ScoreMatrix(i)(j) > max) {
              max = ScoreMatrix(i)(j)
              imax = i
            }
            i += 1
          }
          imax match {
            case 1 => str += 'a'
            case 2 => str += 'c'
            case 3 => str += 'g'
            case 4 => str += 't'
          }
          j += 1
        }
        str
      }

      def newPickup(one: Int, h: Int) {
        if (one == 1) startPos(h) = 1 else startPos(h) += 1
        pickup(h) = " " + seq(h).substring(startPos(h), startPos(h) + lmer)
      }
    }
```

and thanks, i hope someone gonna find my failure.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote raised on this question -- it does mention desired output, the problem op experiences (infinite cycle with no output) and pretty much all the code required to reproduce the problem (though, the code might be overly bloated)

Comment: I wish, I could do that but eclipse debugger don't help I can't say where the problem is .... I write the same program in Java and it's works 100% ... But here I just rewrite from java to scala and somewhere there is an open loop that I can't detected I put everywhere an sysoutprintln("loop working") but I couldn't catch where the problem is !!! So I thought someone cann see the failure , that I can't see

Comment: my comment was addressed to whomever [voted to close your question](http://take.ms/k3ISL) (/and downvoted it)

Comment: I think the problem is that your code needs to be refactored into more bite-sized chunks. As it stands, all the state of the problem is shared and it's hard to unit test for issues. Refactoring would probably help you find the error faster.

Comment: Re-factoring means to rewrite the code or search somehow for the error, how can i solve/search the/for the problem when my debugger don't work, i would really try it, i read in internet that for Scala there is special programs(i hoped someone from the Scala-Programmers could help me) that u can use the debugger,to solve such a Problems, but in Eclipse its some how not working. if there is no idea for solution, i appreciate all of your efforts. Thanks

Comment: do you have a more detailed description of what this program should do?

Comment: Re-factoring has nothing to do with searching for the error. It means (in this case) restructuring the code into smaller pieces where each piece does only one thing, and is easier to test/debug and so find where the error is. It's quite possible to restructure it before finding the error, and as @wheaties says, it will probablh speed up finding the error.

Comment: And some more meaningful variable names as part of that refactoring would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation 'hangs' on this loop:

```
while (k <= i) pickup(k).charAt(m) match {
        case 'a' => ScoreMatrix(1)(m) += 1
        case 'c' => ScoreMatrix(2)(m) += 1
        case 'g' => ScoreMatrix(3)(m) += 1
        case 't' => ScoreMatrix(4)(m) += 1
 }
```

As it stands, the exit condition is never fulfilled because the relation between `k` and `i` never changes. Either increment `k` or decrement `i`.

It looks like programming is not the key aspect of this work, but increased modularity should help contain complexity.

Also, I wonder about the choice of using Scala. There're many areas in this algorithm that would benefit of a more functional approach. In this translation, using Scala in an imperative way gets cumbersome. If you have the opportunity, I'd recommend you to explore a more functional approach to solve this problem.

A tip: The intellij debugger didn't have issues with this code.

Comment: Thanks, that was a big help for the start, i think i can repair the Code now .

Comment: @NoraHagerup do you have a detailed textual description of what this algorithm should do? I could give it a shot using a more functional approach that could help you evaluate and hopefully adopt the approach.

Comment: i just solved the problem ... the program search for a motif(length 8) in sequence that's means, u search for 8 chars in a row in sequence that come as maximum as possible, the Program should then search all the Motifs that he could find and then count how often it comes and give it back that's in short(in Google "branch and bound bioinformatics") its an awesome Program... much fun and much possibilities to Solve... Thanks all